# Navigation drawer with listview highlighting two list items for dialog box case

Tags: android, listview, onclick, navigation-drawer

I have a navigation drawer with listview having 7 items but I am experiencing a small problem when I click on the last item called Logout which opens a dialog box.

The problem is when I click on any item which opens an activity the item gets highlighted properly, but when I click on logout,  the item previously clicked and the logout item clicked both gets highlighted, I want that the logout item should not get highlighted.

My code:

```
public int selected_Drawer_Item = 0;

public class NavArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<String> navList;
    int[] images;

    public NavArrayAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> navList,  
    int[] images) {
        super(context, R.layout.row_item_nav, R.id.txtRow, navList);
        this.context = context;
        this.navList = navList;
        this.images = images;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup  
    parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                 .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_item_nav, parent,  
        false);

        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtRow);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) 
        view.findViewById(R.id.imgNav);
        RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)  
        view.findViewById(R.id.rel_lay_row_item);

        textView.setText(navList.get(position));
        imageView.setImageResource(images[position]);

        if (Constants.selected_Drawer_Item == position) {
            relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor
            (context.getResources().getColor
            (R.color.listviewitemselect));

            textView.setTextColor(context.getResources().
            getColor(R.color.dialogOKtext));
        }

        return view;
    }
}
```

My Listview onitem click

```
mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new  
AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View 
        view, final int i, long l) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
            mDrawerLayout.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    switch (i) {
                        case 0:
                            Intent intent = new  
                            Intent(DrawerActivity.this, Home.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            break;

                        case 1:
                            Intent intent1 = new  
                            Intent(DrawerActivity.this, 
                            Add_Account.class);
                            startActivity(intent1);
                            break;

                        ...... till case 5 same as above

                        case 6:
                            final Dialog dialog = new 
                            Dialog(DrawerActivity.this);
                       dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams dialogParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                            View dislogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.succes_dialog, null);
                            TextView dialogheader = (TextView) dislogView.findViewById(R.id.textDialogHeader);
                            TextView dialogmessage = (TextView) dislogView.findViewById(R.id.textDialogMessage);
                            TextView btnOk = (TextView) dislogView.findViewById(R.id.textDialogOk);
                            TextView btnNo = (TextView) dislogView.findViewById(R.id.textDialogNo);
                            dialogheader.setText("Logout");
                            dialogmessage.setText("Are you sure you want to logout ?");
                            btnNo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            btnOk.setText("YES");
                            btnOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View view) {
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(DrawerActivity.this, Login.class);
                                    Bundle bndlanimation = ActivityOptions.makeCustomAnimation(
                                            getBaseContext(), R.anim.open_translate,
                                            R.anim.close_translate).toBundle();
                                    startActivity(intent, bndlanimation);
                                    finish();
                                }
                            });

                            btnNo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View view) {
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            });

                            dialog.setContentView(dislogView, dialogParams);

                            dialog.show();
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }, 300);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you share your code of onClick and Layout??

Comment: @SahilMunjal i have updated my code , please check , i have added onitemclick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just update if condition in you adapter, your problem will be resolved.

```
if (Constants.selected_Drawer_Item == position) {
    relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor
    (context.getResources().getColor
    (R.color.listviewitemselect));

    textView.setTextColor(context.getResources().
    getColor(R.color.dialogOKtext));
}
```

here change if condition like this

```
if (Constants.selected_Drawer_Item == position && position != 6) {
    /* Here I assumed that your logout menu option's position is 7th so this will work on position 6th*/
    relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor
    (context.getResources().getColor
    (R.color.listviewitemselect));

    textView.setTextColor(context.getResources().
    getColor(R.color.dialogOKtext));
}
```

udpate your onItemClick with these lines,

```
AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View 
    view, final int i, long l) {
    Constants.selected_Drawer_Item = i;
    .........
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
        mDrawerLayout.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                switch (i) {
                    case 0:
                        .............
                        break;
                }
                mDrawerListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }, 300);
}
```

Comment: By this your logout will not visible as a selected options like as other.

Comment: now the logout is getting selected , the other item is not showing as selected , i can manage and make some tweaks with this , thanks for your help.